# Linq to Entity and Contains?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-4.0, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

**Hi,**

I have a linq to sql question like this :

```
tmpAdList1 = (from p in context.Ads
                            join h in context.AdCategories on p.CategoryId equals h.Id
                            join l in context.Location on p.UserLocationId equals l.Id
                            where
                            (adList.S == null || adList.S.Length < 1 || p.Title.Contains(adList.S) || p.Description.Contains(adList.S)) &&
                            (categorylevelOrder.Length < 1 || h.LevelOrder.StartsWith(categorylevelOrder)) &&

                            ((locationIdList != null && lList.Contains(l.Id)) ||
                            (locationLevelOrder.Length < 1 || l.LevelOrder.StartsWith(locationLevelOrder))) &&

                            ((adTypeO1 == AdType.Unknown && adTypeO2 == AdType.Unknown && adTypeO3 == AdType.Unknown && adTypeO4 == AdType.Unknown && adTypeO5 == AdType.Unknown) ||
                            (p.TypeOfAd == (int)adTypeO1 || p.TypeOfAd == (int)adTypeO2 || p.TypeOfAd == (int)adTypeO3 || p.TypeOfAd == (int)adTypeO4 || p.TypeOfAd == (int)adTypeO5)) && //Check for default filters
                            ((AdListShowType)adList.ALS.ST == AdListShowType.Both || adList.ALS.ST == p.OwnerType) &&
                            (p.PublishedDate.HasValue && p.PublishedDate.Value.CompareTo(fetchAdsTo) >= 1) &&
                            ((adOwnerType1.HasValue && adOwnerType2.HasValue) || p.OwnerType == (int)adOwnerType1.Value) &&
                            p.InactivatedDate == null
                            orderby p.CreatedDate descending
                            select p).ToList();
```

**See Edit1 for the whole method**

After this question is runned some more filtering will be done(within the context) but to make this as fast as possible I aim to fetch as little records as possible from the SQL server in the first question.

The problem is that I need to compare locationIdList that is a int[] to the entity. The exception thrown is :

**Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Int32[]'. Only primitive types (such as Int32, String, and Guid) and entity types are supported.**

I have google the problem and this is a known problem, I have however found examples like this :

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 5 };
var result = from s in DB.Something
             where list.Contains(s.Id)
             select s;
```

But this throws the same exception? I have also read that a storedprocedure could solve the problem but I havent found how this work?

Any suggestions?

**BestRegards**

**Edit1 :** The entire method :

```
public List<Ad> GetAds(AdList adList, DateTime fetchAdsTo, out int totalAds)
{
    AdType adTypeO1 = AdType.Unknown;
    AdType adTypeO2 = AdType.Unknown;
    AdType adTypeO3 = AdType.Unknown;
    AdType adTypeO4 = AdType.Unknown;
    AdType adTypeO5 = AdType.Unknown;

    int? adOwnerType1 = null;
    int? adOwnerType2 = null;

    FilterModel filterModel = new FilterModel();

    List<AdCategoryFilter> adCategoryFilterList;
    AdsFilterValues adsFilterValues;
    List<AdsFilterValueWrapper> seartchFilterValueList;
    AdsFilterValueWrapper seartchFilterValue = null;
    List<Ad> tmpAdList1;
    List<Ad> tmpAdList2 = new List<Ad>();

    int locationId = -1;
    int[] locationIdList = null;
    string locationLevelOrder = string.Empty;

    int categoryId = -1;
    string categorylevelOrder = string.Empty;

    AdCategoryFilter adCategoryFilter;

    AdListCompare adListCompare;

    Boolean firstDropDownMatch = false;
    Boolean secondDropDownMatch = false;

    totalAds = 0;

    int machedFilterCount;

    categoryId = AdHandler.Instance.ExtractCategoryId(adList.CS);

    //If there is multiple choises
    //This is the last level, that means that we can check against the ID dircly
    if (adList.LS.L3.Count > 0)
        locationIdList = adList.LS.L3.ToArray();
    else
        locationId = AdHandler.Instance.ExtractLocationId(adList.LS);


    switch ((AdOwnerType)adList.ALS.ST)
    {
        case AdOwnerType.Both:
            adOwnerType1 = (int)AdOwnerType.Private;
            adOwnerType2 = (int)AdOwnerType.Company;
            break;
        case AdOwnerType.Company:
            adOwnerType1 = (int)AdOwnerType.Company;
            break;
        case AdOwnerType.Private:
            adOwnerType1 = (int)AdOwnerType.Private;
            break;
    }

    #region GetFilters
    adCategoryFilterList = filterModel.GetCategoryFilterByCategory(categoryId);
    seartchFilterValueList = FilterHandler.Instance.ConvertAdFilterToModel(adList.F, adCategoryFilterList, FilterType.Display);
    #endregion

    #region Set Default filters (Buy, Let, Sell, Swap, WishRent)
    foreach (AdsFilterValueWrapper filterWrapper in seartchFilterValueList)
    {
        if ((adCategoryFilter = adCategoryFilterList.Where(c => c.Id == filterWrapper.FilterId).FirstOrDefault()) != null)
        {
            switch ((PublicAdFilterKey)adCategoryFilter.PublicAdFilterKey)
            {
                case PublicAdFilterKey.Buy:
                    {
                        if (filterWrapper.AdsFilterValues1.ValueNumber > 0)
                            adTypeO1 = AdType.Buy;
                        break;
                    }
                case PublicAdFilterKey.Let:
                    {
                        if (filterWrapper.AdsFilterValues1.ValueNumber > 0)
                            adTypeO2 = AdType.Let;
                        break;
                    }
                case PublicAdFilterKey.Sell:
                    {
                        if (filterWrapper.AdsFilterValues1.ValueNumber > 0)
                            adTypeO3 = AdType.Sell;
                        break;
                    }
                case PublicAdFilterKey.Swap:
                    {
                        if (filterWrapper.AdsFilterValues1.ValueNumber > 0)
                            adTypeO4 = AdType.Swap;
                        break;
                    }
                case PublicAdFilterKey.WishRent:
                    {
                        if (filterWrapper.AdsFilterValues1.ValueNumber > 0)
                            adTypeO5 = AdType.WishRent;
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    #region Remove default filters fom filterList
    adCategoryFilterList = adCategoryFilterList.Where(c => ((PublicAdFilterKey)c.PublicAdFilterKey) != PublicAdFilterKey.Buy &&
                                    ((PublicAdFilterKey)c.PublicAdFilterKey) != PublicAdFilterKey.Let &&
                                    ((PublicAdFilterKey)c.PublicAdFilterKey) != PublicAdFilterKey.Sell &&
                                    ((PublicAdFilterKey)c.PublicAdFilterKey) != PublicAdFilterKey.Swap &&
                                    ((PublicAdFilterKey)c.PublicAdFilterKey) != PublicAdFilterKey.WishRent).ToList();
    #endregion
    #endregion

    var lList = adList.LS.L3.ToList<int>(); //new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 5 };


    using (BissEntities context = new BissEntities())
    {
        if (categoryId > 0)
            categorylevelOrder = context.AdCategories.Where(c => c.Id.Equals(categoryId)).FirstOrDefault().LevelOrder.Trim();
        if (locationId > 0)
            locationLevelOrder = context.Location.Where(c => c.Id.Equals(locationId)).FirstOrDefault().LevelOrder.Trim();

        tmpAdList1 = (from p in context.Ads
                        join h in context.AdCategories on p.CategoryId equals h.Id
                        join l in context.Location on p.UserLocationId equals l.Id
                        where
                        (adList.S == null || adList.S.Length < 1 || p.Title.Contains(adList.S) || p.Description.Contains(adList.S)) &&
                        (categorylevelOrder.Length < 1 || h.LevelOrder.StartsWith(categorylevelOrder)) &&

                        ((locationIdList != null && lList.Contains(l.Id)) ||
                        (locationLevelOrder.Length < 1 || l.LevelOrder.StartsWith(locationLevelOrder))) &&

                        ((adTypeO1 == AdType.Unknown && adTypeO2 == AdType.Unknown && adTypeO3 == AdType.Unknown && adTypeO4 == AdType.Unknown && adTypeO5 == AdType.Unknown) ||
                        (p.TypeOfAd == (int)adTypeO1 || p.TypeOfAd == (int)adTypeO2 || p.TypeOfAd == (int)adTypeO3 || p.TypeOfAd == (int)adTypeO4 || p.TypeOfAd == (int)adTypeO5)) && //Check for default filters
                        ((AdListShowType)adList.ALS.ST == AdListShowType.Both || adList.ALS.ST == p.OwnerType) &&
                        (p.PublishedDate.HasValue && p.PublishedDate.Value.CompareTo(fetchAdsTo) >= 1) &&
                        ((adOwnerType1.HasValue && adOwnerType2.HasValue) || p.OwnerType == (int)adOwnerType1.Value) &&
                        p.InactivatedDate == null
                        orderby p.CreatedDate descending
                        select p).ToList();

        #region Filter collection
        foreach (Ad ad in tmpAdList1)
        {
            machedFilterCount = 0;
            adListCompare = AdListCompare.NotCompered;

            if (adCategoryFilterList.Count > 0)
            {                     
                //Loop the filters that belongs to the choosen category
                foreach (AdCategoryFilter existingFilter in adCategoryFilterList)
                {
                    //Se if the ad has the proper filter If not return it
                    if ((adsFilterValues = ad.AdsFilterValues.Where(c => c.CategoryFilterId == existingFilter.Id).FirstOrDefault()) != null || existingFilter.PublicAdFilterKey > 0)
                    {

                        //If the filter is not a regular value filter but a filter pointed to a property on the ad
                        //Then extract the correct value and use it
                        if (existingFilter.PublicAdFilterKey > 0)
                        {
                            adsFilterValues = new AdsFilterValues();
                            adsFilterValues.CategoryFilterId = existingFilter.Id;

                            switch ((PublicAdFilterKey)existingFilter.PublicAdFilterKey)
                            {
                                case PublicAdFilterKey.Price:
                                    {
                                        adsFilterValues.ValueNumber = ad.Price;
                                        break;
                                    }
                            }

                        }

                        if ((seartchFilterValue = seartchFilterValueList.Where(c => c.AdsFilterValues1.CategoryFilterId == adsFilterValues.CategoryFilterId).FirstOrDefault()) != null)
                        {
                            firstDropDownMatch = false;
                            secondDropDownMatch = false;
                            adListCompare = AdListCompare.Compared;

                            switch ((FilterControlType)existingFilter.DisplayFilterControlType)
                            {
                                case FilterControlType.TwoDropDown:

                                    //Check so the first dropdown value compare
                                    //If the index is the first then any value will do
                                    if (seartchFilterValue.FilterIndexPosition1 == FilterIndexPosition.First)
                                        firstDropDownMatch = true;
                                    else
                                    {
                                        if (adsFilterValues.ValueNumber.Value >= seartchFilterValue.AdsFilterValues1.ValueNumber.Value)
                                            firstDropDownMatch = true;
                                    }

                                    if (firstDropDownMatch)
                                    {
                                        //Check so the second dropdown value compare
                                        //If the index is the last then any value will do
                                        if (seartchFilterValue.FilterIndexPosition2 == FilterIndexPosition.Last)
                                            secondDropDownMatch = true;
                                        else
                                        {
                                            if (adsFilterValues.ValueNumber.Value <= seartchFilterValue.AdsFilterValues2.ValueNumber.Value)
                                                secondDropDownMatch = true;
                                        }

                                        if (secondDropDownMatch)
                                            adListCompare = AdListCompare.Approved;
                                    }

                                    break;
                                case FilterControlType.DropDown:

                                    //Check so the first dropdown value compare
                                    //If the index is the first then any value will do
                                    if (seartchFilterValue.FilterIndexPosition1 == FilterIndexPosition.First)
                                    {
                                        if (adsFilterValues.ValueNumber.Value <= seartchFilterValue.AdsFilterValues1.ValueNumber.Value)
                                            firstDropDownMatch = true;
                                    }
                                    if (seartchFilterValue.FilterIndexPosition1 == FilterIndexPosition.Last)
                                    {
                                        if (adsFilterValues.ValueNumber.Value >= seartchFilterValue.AdsFilterValues1.ValueNumber.Value)
                                            firstDropDownMatch = true;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        if (adsFilterValues.ValueNumber.Value == seartchFilterValue.AdsFilterValues1.ValueNumber.Value)
                                            firstDropDownMatch = true;
                                    }

                                    if (firstDropDownMatch)
                                        adListCompare = AdListCompare.Approved;

                                    break;
                                case FilterControlType.TextBox:
                                    if (adsFilterValues.ValueString.Equals(seartchFilterValue.AdsFilterValues1.ValueString))
                                        adListCompare = AdListCompare.Approved;
                                    break;
                                case FilterControlType.CheckBox:
                                    if (adsFilterValues.ValueNumber != null && adsFilterValues.ValueNumber.Value == seartchFilterValue.AdsFilterValues1.ValueNumber.Value)
                                        adListCompare = AdListCompare.Approved;
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    adListCompare = AdListCompare.NotCompered;
                                    break;
                            }

                            //If no value is set, then break;
                            if (adListCompare != AdListCompare.Approved)
                                break;

                            machedFilterCount++;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //If the ad is missing the filter then return it anyway, it might as well be correct
                        adListCompare = AdListCompare.Approved;
                        machedFilterCount = adCategoryFilterList.Count();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                adListCompare = AdListCompare.Approved;
                machedFilterCount = adCategoryFilterList.Count();
            }


            if (adListCompare == AdListCompare.Approved && machedFilterCount == adCategoryFilterList.Count())
                tmpAdList2.Add(ad);
        }
        #endregion

        if (adList.ALS.OB == (int)AdListOrderBy.Price)
            tmpAdList2 = tmpAdList2.OrderBy(c => c.Price).ToList();


        totalAds = tmpAdList2.Count();

        return tmpAdList2.Skip((adList.ALS.P - 1) * adList.ALS.CP).Take(adList.ALS.CP).ToList();
    }
}
```

**Edit 2: update**

The **main GetAd** Method :

```
public List<Ad> GetAds(AdList adList, DateTime fetchAdsTo, out int totalAds)
        {
            LocationModel locationModel = new LocationModel();
            FilterModel filterModel = new FilterModel();

            List<AdCategoryFilter> adCategoryFilterList;
            List<AdsFilterValueWrapper> seartchFilterValueList;

            int categoryId = -1;
            List<Ad> outputList;

            totalAds = 0;

            #region Fetch the first ads by location
            outputList = GetAdsByLocations(locationModel.GetLocationOrderList(adList.GetLocationIds()), fetchAdsTo, false);
            if(outputList.Count < 1)
                return outputList;
            #endregion

            #region GetFilters
            categoryId = AdHandler.Instance.ExtractCategoryId(adList.CS);
            adCategoryFilterList = filterModel.GetCategoryFilterByCategory(categoryId);
            seartchFilterValueList = FilterHandler.Instance.ConvertAdFilterToModel(adList.F, adCategoryFilterList, FilterType.Display);
            #endregion

            #region Filter Default filters (Buy, Let, Sell, Swap, WishRent)
            FilterDefaultCustomFilters(outputList, adCategoryFilterList, seartchFilterValueList);
            if (outputList.Count == 0)
                return outputList;
            else
            {
                #region Remove default filters fom filterList
                adCategoryFilterList = adCategoryFilterList.Where(c => ((PublicAdFilterKey)c.PublicAdFilterKey) != PublicAdFilterKey.Buy &&
                                                ((PublicAdFilterKey)c.PublicAdFilterKey) != PublicAdFilterKey.Let &&
                                                ((PublicAdFilterKey)c.PublicAdFilterKey) != PublicAdFilterKey.Sell &&
                                                ((PublicAdFilterKey)c.PublicAdFilterKey) != PublicAdFilterKey.Swap &&
                                                ((PublicAdFilterKey)c.PublicAdFilterKey) != PublicAdFilterKey.WishRent).ToList();
                #endregion
            }
            #endregion

            #region Filter Custom filters
            this.FilterCustomFilters(outputList, adCategoryFilterList, seartchFilterValueList);
            #endregion

            #region Order
            switch ((AdListOrderBy)adList.ALS.OB)
            {
                case AdListOrderBy.Price:
                    outputList = outputList.OrderBy(c => c.Price).ToList(); break;
                case AdListOrderBy.Latest:
                    outputList = outputList.OrderByDescending(c => c.PublishedDate).ToList(); break;
            }
            #endregion

            #region Total Ad Count
            totalAds = outputList.Count();
            #endregion

            #region Paging
            outputList = outputList.Skip((adList.ALS.P - 1) * adList.ALS.CP).Take(adList.ALS.CP).ToList();
            #endregion

            return outputList;
        }
```

**GetAdByLocation**

```
public List<Ad> GetAdsByLocations(string[] locationLevelOrderList, DateTime? fetchAdsTo, Boolean inactive) //, List<Ad> adList = null)
{
    List<Ad> output;

    using (BissEntities context = new BissEntities())
    {
        if (fetchAdsTo.HasValue)
        {
            if (locationLevelOrderList.Count() == 0)
            {
                output = (from a in context.Ads
                            join l in context.Location on a.UserLocationId equals l.Id
                            where a.InactivatedDate.HasValue == inactive &&
                            (a.PublishedDate.HasValue && a.PublishedDate.Value.CompareTo(fetchAdsTo.Value) >= 1)
                            select a).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                output = (from a in context.Ads
                            join l in context.Location on a.UserLocationId equals l.Id
                            where a.InactivatedDate.HasValue == inactive &&
                            (a.PublishedDate.HasValue && a.PublishedDate.Value.CompareTo(fetchAdsTo.Value) >= 1) &&
                            (locationLevelOrderList.Where(c => l.LevelOrder.StartsWith(c)).FirstOrDefault() != null) 
                            select a).ToList();
            }

        }
        else
        {
            if (locationLevelOrderList.Count() == 0)
            {
                output = (from a in context.Ads
                            join l in context.Location on a.UserLocationId equals l.Id
                            where a.InactivatedDate.HasValue == inactive
                            select a).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                output = (from a in context.Ads
                            join l in context.Location on a.UserLocationId equals l.Id
                            where a.InactivatedDate.HasValue == inactive &&
                            (locationLevelOrderList.Count() == 0 || locationLevelOrderList.Where(c => l.LevelOrder.StartsWith(c)).FirstOrDefault() != null)
                            select a).ToList();
            }
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

**Note :** The methods in main GetAd that begins with Filter in name will only work with the collection (no database actions)

Comment: That is an unnecessarily complicated query.  You should perform your null checks on the other collections elsewhere outside of the query.  I'd start off by simplifying it first.  That might mean breaking up your query into parts and combining them into a larger query.  Doing so will probably correct the problem automatically.

Comment: @Jeff M > Thanks, I have added the entire method now where you can see why its so complex. I do however not follow you, could you explain in grater detail?

Comment: So many code. You must localize your problem to simple code snippet or most people will simply skip your question.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka > sorry I have now added the linq to sql code separately in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last example works in Entity framework 4. If you get exception your application is the most probably built as .NET 3.5 with first version of Entity framework which didn't support `Contains`.

Comment: Oh! So EF4 finally supports Contains?  Didn't know that!  Great news indeed!  Learn something new everyday.  +1

Comment: @SnowJim: Write your query in SQL so we can understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: > I have no tried this in a simplier linq to entity and it works. So now I will refactore the complex method in to smaller parts. But as I see it the first method will have to fetch alot of ads (GetAdsByLocation) then the collection will be filtered in all the other methods. Is this the way to go? Much of the filtering do not need to consult the database, but there is some that will have to check the database to be able to filter.

Comment: @SnowJim: In linq-to-entities everything runs on the database, there is no *this part will run here and this part will run there*. If you want to run some filtering in the application you must switch to linq-to-objects (calling `AsEnumerable` or `ToList`) but it will transfer all unfiltered data to your application and you will not be able to switch back to linq-to-entities.

Answer (score 7):

Within your query, you have the comparison:

```
 ... locationIdList != null ...
```

Seeing as `locationIdList` is of type `int[]`, the query cannot be translated since it only supports simple comparisons (as the error states).

You should be performing these checks outside the query, not within them.  However since they are initialized within the method, you should just ensure that they are initialized and omit the check as it is unnecessary.

---

I would strongly recommend refactoring the whole method and the query.  That is terribly long and hard to follow.  Move the blocks of code into separate methods performing a small part of what you need then put them all together.  It will make your code easier to maintain and correcting errors such such as this much easier.

Comment: M > Thanks, I will try to refactor the method. I first thought is to make a method that only get all ads from database that belongs to the correct location(GetAdsByLocation) , then I will brake upp all the other checks in methods and only do this on the collection I get from the first method(GetAdsByLocation). This will mean that there could be alot of ads in the collection but I do not see how to do it any other way? Pleas advice

Comment: @Jim: That's a good start I'd think.  Additionally, you should probably move all the blocks of code that span more than 15-20 lines into their own method.  You might want to consider restructuring that last block too.  A moving it to a separate method just won't be enough.

Comment: M > Thanks, Take a look on Edit2, this is the new update of the same method. Does this look better? Is there anything more I should refactor?

Comment: @Jim: I'd say that's a BIG improvement over what you had originally.  Though I have to ask first, are you still getting the expected results?  Are you still getting that error?  No point in refactoring if you break the code.  Provided that it is correct, it would be easier to suggest improvements to the code.

Comment: M > Yeas it workes grate but I do need some more testing to be absolutly sure. The "Contains" on simple arrays do definitely work in .NET 4.0.